# Get the new camera position with onmousemove event on a sphere object and transforming it onto 2D map location

Tags: three.js, onmousemove

I have made a sphere object with a camera.position(0,0,1) and using orbit controls(camera). Now when i drag mouse on my sphere either of the sides how can i get my new camera positions and transform them onto a 2-D map ? I have searched but could not find any relevant sources if somebody can help, it could be really great-full.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera position is stored as a vector3 in camera.position, you can also add the face direction with controls.target. With the camera.position vector you can easily calculate the position on a 2D map with the x and z position of the camera.